# Scrolling up to page top when changing tabbedPanel as PartialRefresh on Domino 9 -XPages

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

When I test the code below on Domino 8.5.3 FP6, TabbedPanel can change the tab contents without moving back to page top as I expected.
However, when I test the same code on Domino 9.0.1FP3, my browser scrolls up to the page top regardless tab action run as partialRefresh.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:text tagName="h2" escape="false" style="padding-bottom:600px;"
        value="TabbedPanel PartialRefresh Test on Domino9">
    </xp:text>

    <xp:tabbedPanel id="tabbedPanel1" partialRefresh="true"
        selectedTab="tabPanel2" partialExecute="true">
        <xp:tabPanel label="First Tab" id="tabPanel1">
            first Tab
        </xp:tabPanel>
        <xp:tabPanel label="Second Tab" id="tabPanel2">
            Second Tab
        </xp:tabPanel>
    </xp:tabbedPanel>
</xp:view>
```

How can I keep the browser scroll position when changing tabs on Domino 9?
Any advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have done some test with your piece of code. You are right on `Domino 8.5.3` all works perfect, but not on `Domino 9.0.1`.

A workaround would be, to set the attribute `partialRefresh="false"`. With this setting on `Domino 9.0.1` the focus moves up to top and immediatly back to your `<xp:tabbedpanel>`. From the perspective of usability it isn't the best solution but it works.

*Adapted Code:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:text tagName="h2" escape="false" style="padding-bottom:600px;"
        value="TabbedPanel PartialRefresh Test on Domino9">
    </xp:text>

    <xp:tabbedPanel id="tabbedPanel1" selectedTab="tabPanel2" partialRefresh="false" partialExecute="true">
        <xp:tabPanel label="First Tab" id="tabPanel1">first Tab</xp:tabPanel>
        <xp:tabPanel label="Second Tab" id="tabPanel2">Second Tab</xp:tabPanel>
    </xp:tabbedPanel>

</xp:view>
```

Comment: Thank you, Georg. I will take your suggestion if there are no other better solutions.